# How to actually create a quantum harmonic oscillator potential well?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, harmonic-oscillator

Classically, to put a particle in a harmonic oscillator potential I can just hook it up to a spring. But how is $V=\frac{1}{2}m \omega^2 x^2$ actually created for a particle like, say, an electron?
Of course I know that any potential can be approximated to take the form like $V$ about a local minima, but that's not the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you insist on electrons? For positive ions a search term is “Einstein solid,” which is the source of cartoons where the atoms in a crystal are connected to each other by imaginary springs and are free to “jiggle.” In the Einstein solid, the jiggling is quantized.

Comment: Here is a list of wikipedia articles you might look into:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_tweezers#Harmonic_potential_approximation
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_solid
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Applications
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_quantization